# Print the last word of String inside an array with only one loop

Tags: c

The program gets me out of the loop, it shows me in check that it is coming to `NULL`
Although it should continue to advance to the following letters in the string.

Thanks to all the assistants

```
void main()
{
    char string[2][10] = { "lior","king" };
    int words, letter;

    for (words=0,letter = 0;words<2 , string[words][letter] != NULL;)
    {  
        letter++; 
        if (string[words][letter] = NULL)
        {
            printf("%c\n", string[words][letter - 1]);
            words++;
        }
    }
 }
```

The ambition is that when it reaches the end of the first word, it will print the first letter and advance to the next string

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the exepected output.

Comment: `string[words][letter] = NULL` <- assignment operator instead of comparison, use `==` (and turn on and read warnings)

Comment: `words<2 , string[words][letter] != NULL` <- the first statement `words<2` has no effect, did you mean to write `words<2 && string[words][letter] != NULL)`?

Comment: Hence always best to put the non-assignable value to the left, then the compiler will pick it up. Also no bounds checking for value of words or letter used later in code.

Comment: @ChrisBD This is correct, but uuuugly... A good compiler will warn anyway (suggest extra parentheses...)

Answer (score 1):

This condition in the loop

```
words<2 , string[words][letter] != NULL;
```

is wrong. It seems you mean just

```
words<2
```

The first statement in the body pf the loop

```
letter++;
```

is also wrong because you skipped the index 0.

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    char string[][N] = { "lior","king" };
    const size_t M = sizeof( string ) / sizeof( *string );

    for ( size_t word = 0, letter = 0; word < M; ) 
    {  
        if  (string[word][letter] == '\0'  )
        {
            if ( letter != 0 ) printf( "%c\n", string[word][letter - 1] );
            letter = 0;
            ++word;
        }
        else
        {
            ++letter;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
r
g
```